# How to check negative integer values ? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a below query to see what are the possitive and negative integer values from a table fields. But I am not sure how to fetch only negative integer values.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttdata NO-UNDO
FIELD iValue1 AS INTEGER
FIELD iValue2 AS INTEGER
.

CREATE ttdata.
ASSIGN
iValue1 = 122
iValue2 = -122
.

FOR EACH ttdata NO-LOCK:
  DISP iValue1 iValue2.
END.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a query just about one field `where field < 0`

```swift
FOR EACH ttdata NO-LOCK 
   WHERE ttData.iValue2 < 0:
    DISP iValue1 iValue2.
END.
```

when you have two fields with `or`

```swift
FOR EACH ttdata NO-LOCK 
   WHERE ttData.iValue2 < 0 
      OR ttData.iValue1 < 0:
    DISP iValue1 iValue2.
END.
```

but when you use the `where or` on a database table, you should have 2 indexes where `iValue1` and `iValue2` is the first field, otherwise it will be slow and a full table scan. On a temp-table it will be fine without an index

Comment: It will be slow without with, or without ,the OR if there are not appropriate indexes. But if there are appropriate indexes the OR is not especially harmful.  The two field example needs two indexes: one where iValue1 is the leading component and another where iValue2 is the leading component. This will still result in a "range match" because of the "<" but it will at least not be a table scan.

Comment: thank you Tom, yes it works well with 2 seperated indexes per field
https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=62cdc9823fb02369b254a0b5

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WHEN expressions` :

```swift
FOR EACH ttdata NO-LOCK:
  DISPLAY ttdata.iValue1 WHEN ttdata.iValue1 < 0 
          ttdata.iValue2 WHEN ttdata.iValue2 < 0.
END.
```